# go routines and channel to send response

Tags: go

I have the following code:
i have a list to go through and do something with a value from that list, and so i thought of using go routines, but i need to use a max number of go routines, and then in go routine i need to make a call that will get a return of response, err, when the err is different from null I need to terminate all the go routines and return an http response, and if there is no err I need to terminate the go routines and return an http response,

When I have few values ​​it works ok, but when I have many values ​​I have a problem, because when I call cancel I will still have go routines trying to send to the response channel that is already closed and I keep getting errors from:

> goroutine 36 [chan send]:

```
type response struct {
    value string
}

func Testing() []response {

    fakeValues := getFakeValues()

    maxParallel := 25
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    if len(fakeValues) < maxParallel {
        maxParallel = len(fakeValues)
    }

    type responseChannel struct {
        Response response
        Err      error
    }

    reqChan := make(chan string) //make this an unbuffered channel
    resChan := make(chan responseChannel)

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(maxParallel)
    for i := 0; i < maxParallel; i++ {
        go func(ctx context.Context, ch chan string, resChan chan responseChannel) {
            for {
                select {
                case val := <-ch:
                    resp, err := getFakeResult(val)
                    resChan <- responseChannel{
                        Response: resp,
                        Err:      err,
                    }

                case <-ctx.Done():
                    wg.Done()
                    return
                }
            }
        }(ctx, reqChan, resChan)
    }

    go func() {
        for _, body := range fakeValues {
            reqChan <- body
        }

        close(reqChan)
        cancel()

    }()

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(resChan)
    }()

    var hasErr error
    response := make([]response, 0, len(fakeValues))
    for res := range resChan {
        if res.Err != nil {
            hasErr = res.Err
            cancel()
            break
        }

        response = append(response, res.Response)
    }

    if hasErr != nil {
        // return responses.ErrorResponse(hasErr) // returns http response
    }

    //  return responses.Accepted(response, nil) // returns http response
    return nil
}

func getFakeValues() []string {
    return []string{"a"}
}

func getFakeResult(val string) (response, error) {
    if val == "" {
        return response{}, fmt.Errorf("ooh noh:%s", val)
    }

    return response{
        value: val,
    }, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The workers end up blocked on sending to resChan because it's not buffered, and after an error, nothing reads from it.
You can either make resChan buffered, with a size at least as large as maxParallel. Or check to see if the context was canceled, e.g. change the `resChan <-` to

```
select {
case resChan <- responseChannel{
                    Response: resp,
                    Err:      err,
}:
case <-ctx.Done():
}
```

Comment: thanks, do you think there is a better way to do this?

Comment: I think checking ctx.Done() is the best way to do it.

Comment: The overall approach looks fine, I've seen it done that way a few times.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems with your solution:

First, if your `fakeValues` slice has more items than `maxParallel`+1, your program will block on this part:

```
for _, body := range fakeValues {
        reqChan <- body
    }
```

How does this happen? As you start putting values in `reqChan`, each started goroutine will read one value from the `reqChan` and try to write the response to `resChan`. But, since `resChan` is still not reading responses, each goroutine will block there (writing to `resChan`). Eventually, once each goroutine is blocked, reading from the `reqChan` is blocked as well and you cannot put any more values in it (apart from one buffered value).

Second, you are passing the context to your goroutines, but you are not doing anything with it. You can use `ctx.Done()` channel to get a signal to exit the goroutine. Something like this:

```
go func(ctx context.Context, ch chan string, resChan chan responseChannel) {
          for {
                select {
                    case val := <-ch:
                        resp, err := getFakeResult(val)
                        resChan <- responseChannel{
                             Response: resp,
                             Err:      err,
                        }
 
                    case <- ctx.Done():
                         return
                }
            }
        }(ctx, reqChan, resChan)
```

Now, to tie everything together so that there are no deadlocks, no race conditions, and no situations where values are not processed, a few other changes need to be made. I've posted the entire code below.

```
func Testing() []response {

    fakeValues := getFakeValues()

    maxParallel := 25
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    if len(fakeValues) < maxParallel {
        maxParallel = len(fakeValues)
    }

    type responseChannel struct {
        Response response
        Err      error
    }

    reqChan := make(chan string) //make this an unbuffered channel
    resChan := make(chan responseChannel)

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(maxParallel)
    for i := 0; i < maxParallel; i++ {
        go func(ctx context.Context, ch chan string, resChan chan responseChannel) {
              for {
                    select {
                        case val := <-ch:
                            resp, err := getFakeResult(val)
                            resChan <- responseChannel{
                                 Response: resp,
                                 Err:      err,
                            }
     
                        case <- ctx.Done():
                             wg.Done()
                             return
                    }
                }
             wg.Done()
            }(ctx, reqChan, resChan)
    }

    go func() {
       for _, body := range fakeValues {
          reqChan <- body
       }

       close(reqChan)
       //putting cancel here so that it can terminate all goroutines when all values are read from reqChan
       cancel()
       
    }()

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(resChan)
    }()

    var hasErr error
    response := make([]response, 0, len(fakeValues))
    for res := range resChan {
        if res.Err != nil {
            hasErr = res.Err
            cancel()
            break
        }

        response = append(response, res.Response)
    }

    if hasErr != nil {
        return responses.ErrorResponse(hasErr) // returns http response
    }

    return responses.Accepted(response, nil) // returns http response
}
```

In short, the changes are:

- `reqChan` is an unbuffered channel, as this will help in cases where values might not get processed when we close goroutines that read data from buffered channels.
- worker goroutines have been changed to accommodate the cases of both exiting when error happens and when there is no more data from `reqChan` to process. `wg.Done()` is executed when the context is canceled to ensure that `resChan` is eventually closed.
- separate goroutine is created to put the data in the `reqChan` without blocking the program, close it afterward, and cancel the context.

Comment: hi I have a problem, I'm getting invalid values,
when there is no return err, there are times when it keeps sending a message and with that the message goes empty, and then an empty response is being sent to the response channel

Comment: I need the value that I am sending in the func to be different from empty, otherwise it will return an error, and even in a case of success, it is sometimes calling this func with empty values ​​and returning error when it should not return, for having made calls to more

Comment: In which circumstances you're getting invalid values? Is that because of the way the code is written, or because your source of messages can sometimes send invalid values?

Comment: Laletovi I will update the question with the code trying to better explain the problem

Comment: I have a list of fake values ​​: []string{"a"}, I will send it to the channel: reqChan, the expected result is the return of the value "A" and err nil, it is returning the A and is like the channel of req would receive another empty message where it would enter the if : if val == "" {
return response{}, fmt.Errorf("ooh noh:%s", val)
}